# Express warehouse constraint by gecode(Ch15 of the gecode document)

Tags: c++, constraint-programming, gecode

Can't understand the constraint on page192, "Do not exceed capacity".

```
IntSetArgs c(n_warehouses);
for(int w = 0; w < n_warehouses; ++w){
  c[w] = IntSet(0, capacity[w]);
  //IntSet(0, 1) == {}, {0}, {1}, {0, 1}
}
count(*this, supplier, c, ICL_DOM);
```

The document say the count function build a constraint which equal to "Do not exceed capacity".
But I don't know why?

1 : what is the different with and without ICL_DOM?

2 : According to 4.4.8(pg 63)

if c is not a set but an IntArrayArgs and without ICL_DOM, it is like posting the 
constraint as following?

```
int capacity[] = {1, 4, 2, 1, 3};

supplier[0] == 0  == c[0] == 1
supplier[0] == 1  == c[1] == 4
supplier[0] == 2  == c[2] == 2
supplier[0] == 3  == c[3] == 1
supplier[0] == 4  == c[4] == 3

supplier[1] == 0 == c[0] == 1 //and so on
```

What if the c is a set? is this mean that the constraint would become

```
supplier[0] == 0 == c[0] == 0, 1
supplier[0] == 1 == c[1] == 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
//....
supplier[1] == 0 == c[0] == 0, 1
supplier[1] == 1 == c[1] == 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 //and so on?
```

I don't get why this could make the "Do not exceed capacity" constraint hold.

for me, it should be(pseudo codes)

```
rel(*this, sum(supplier == 0) <= 1);
rel(*this, sum(supplier == 1) <= 4);
rel(*this, sum(supplier == 2) <= 2);
rel(*this, sum(supplier == 3) <= 1);
rel(*this, sum(supplier == 4) <= 3);
```